# How do I declare the root as global and set it to null to indicate an empty tree in a structure in c++?

Tags: c++

As a beginner in c++, I have encountered a problem trying to implement a structure for binary search tree. Shown below is part of my code but c++ kept reminding me that the "data member initializer is not allowed".

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct BstNode{int key; BstNode*Left; BstNode*Right; BstNode*root = NULL;};
```

Comment: `BstNode* = NULL;` misses a name, what are you trying to do there?

Comment: Declaring a struct should be `struct`, not `Struct`. You must name all declarations, which you've forgotten for the last one. You also need to put semicolon after the struct declaration.

Comment: What is `BstNode* = NULL;` supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to be "root"

Comment: Are you compiling in c++11 (the 2011 standard) or newer? I would expect any modern compiler to default to at least the 2011 standard but a lot of people use very old compilers. Using `NULL` could indicate that you are using some old standard. In c++11 and newer you should use `nullptr`  instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply write

```
BstNode *root = nullptr;
```

outside of the struct.